# 2 column responsive layout with variable sized and positioned elements

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I want to accomplish this kind of responsive layout that would also put the blocks in the right order. It's easy if you use grid and just let the whole right column go under left for a single column, but I want to make the single blocks to be distributed in the right order.

Here's how it should look on large screen (2-column):

[image: Example of 2-column layout on large screen]

And here's how it should look on smaller screen (1-column):

[image: Example of single column layout on smaller screen]

The blocks are aligned:

- 1 & 4 = left
- 2 & 3 = right
- 5 & 6 = center

All the blocks have different width&height (random) and I want to achieve this kind of positioning - and once again - the block order is important.
(the column widths on large screen are the same.. I just sketched it a bit too fast)

I already tried to achieve this with different HTML & CSS markup but failed every time. I also experimented with javascript that reorders boxes in DOM but had problems, since some boxes also contain other javascripts and codes which failed to execute after DOM has been modified.

So I am looking for a simplest solution, preferably only using html+css and no javascript if it is possible.

Comment: I can't find any sort of pattern in there... with a quick look it seems to require some sort of artificial intelligency.. based on what do you decide whether something should stack to `left/right` or `center` aligned..? on a second though, this will require a full plugin level code...

Comment: you can forget about left/right/center alignment.. this can be done with divs that have classes for each alignment and is not a problem.

Comment: my problem is how to make a layout that has elements randomly distributed in 2 columns but when it falls into one column, the order of the elements should be the same - I guess it can be done with masonry or smth similar but how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed using Masonry.

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div style="margin-top:0px; text-align: left"><div style="width:70%;height: 200px">1</div></div>
    <div style="margin-top:50px; text-align: right"><div style="width:80%;height:170px">2</div></div>
    <div style="margin-top:50px; text-align: right"><div  style="width:60%">3</div></div>
    <div style="margin-top:50px; text-align: left"><div  style="width:40%; height:150px">4</div></div>
    <div style="margin-top:50px; text-align: center"><div  style="width:60%">5</div></div>
    <div style="margin-top:50px; text-align: center"><div  style="width:80%;height:100px">6</div></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
    #wrapper {
        width: 100%;
        max-width: 800px;
    }

    #wrapper > div {
        width: 40%;
        max-width: 350px;
    }

    #wrapper > div > div {
        display: inline-block;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 50px 0;
        background: #000;
        color: #fff;
    }
```

Javascript (using jquery):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#wrapper").masonry({
                         columnWidth: 380,
                          gutter: 20
                          });
});
```

Example can be found at http://jsfiddle.net/sinusiks/w99te/4/